# Webdriver - Not stable results in very stable environment

Tags: webdriver

As many people before me, I have a problem with webdriver stability.

I have a test on stable page, using ID's or dummy-proof xpaths, locating to existing fields (not to dynamically loaded but present from the beginning of the test), I used reset focus with clicking somewhere aside and also Thread.Sleep almost after every statement (which I don't consider as a good practise at all). And from five runs, only one or two is successful (plus/minus, statistically).

The most often cause is value not filled in the field (correctly located, existing field, not hidden under a dropdown from the listbox above and so one) and subsequent assert fail. I add a console output to my locating methods so I know that an element was found out (present, visible) and only the value was not filled in.

The most mysterious one is "Sendkeys(Keys.Delete)" used on value "6000.01" which gives "0.01" sometimes instead of an empty field. I have added a repeat of this delete but it is very strange.

Is there anything I have missed? A method I can use except these mentioned above? Was anyone struggling with similar problems and got some success?

Thank you for any advise.

Answer (score 0):

From your question I'm assuming that you're having a problem clearing an input WebElement using 'Sendkeys(Keys.Delete)'.

Have you tried using the WebElement.clear() method to do so? For example:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("example"));
element.clear();
```

If I'm approaching your question incorrectly please can you provide a sample of the HTML and WebDriver source code you are having a problem with?